# Is support for Angular 2 out for Modern UI?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am interested in using office UI Fabric in SPFx client side webparts. But I would prefer using Angular 2 with a combination of Office UI Fabric. Is support for Office UI fabric along with Angular 2 rolled out for SPFx web parts?

Any help/suggestions on the same would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Angular 2, but Elaine Van Bergen (tech evangelist @MSFT) mentioned at Microsoft Tech Summit Sydney that there's some work with Angular 5.  There were also some recent sessions at [SPS Lisbon describing the use of Angular Elements](https://twitter.com/sebastienlevert/status/931940292395069440).